# Create Keyword Object Perl Microsoft::AdCenter

Tags: perl, api, keyword, ads

So I looked at the perldoc for the Microsoft::AdCenter module and it shows this as an example of how to create a keyword object:

`~$ perldoc Microsoft::AdCenter`

```
#Create a Keyword object
my $keyword = Microsoft::AdCenter::V7::CampaignManagementService::Keyword->new
           ->Text("some text")
           ->BroadMatchBid(Microsoft::AdCenter::V7::CampaignManagementService::Bid->new->Amount(0.1))
           ->ExactMatchBid(Microsoft::AdCenter::V7::CampaignManagementService::Bid->new->Amount(0.1));
```

However, doesn't this violate the new policy of using only one match type per keyword?

Campaign Management changes:

"Previously, you would create a single Keyword object and specify a bid value for each match that you wanted to bid on (for example, exact match or phrase match). If you did not specify a bid value at the keyword-level, adCenter used the default bid value specified at the ad group level.

Now, you must create a Keyword object for each match type that you want to bid on. For example, to bid on the keyword car by using exact match and phrase match, create a Keyword object and set the Text element to car and the ExactMatchBid element to a bid amount. Then, create a second Keyword object and set the Text element to car and PhraseMatchBid to a bid amount. When you add the keywords, you’ll get a unique keyword ID for each keyword and match-type combination."

It seems like the perldoc is not up to date. These perldocs were last updated on 2011-05-15. When will the perldocs be updated?

Also when will the [Msdn API Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb671833(v=msads.70).aspx) be updated?

[Add Keywords in Perl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc300296.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft:

This functionality in which you described where a new keyword object needs to be created for each match type being bid on is being rolled out in gradual phases in the near future. The documentation for this new functionality will be updated to reflect these functionality changes.

Please watch the [Microsoft AdCenter API Developer Blog](http://community.microsoftadvertising.com/blogs/api/default.aspx?) and [AdCenter API Release Notes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee703976.aspx)  for more updates on this new functionality coming soon.